# Linked List not printing

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to create a simple linked list using C, I think I was able to construct the linked list itself, but when I try and print it, it prints the value of the last node instead of all the values in the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <alloca.h>

typedef int DATA;
struct Node
{
    DATA d;
    struct Node *next;
};

void printList(struct Node **head)
{
    struct Node *newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *temp;
    temp = *head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
       printf("%d \n", temp->d);
       temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Node *newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *head = newNode;
    struct Node *temp = newNode;
    head->d = 1;
    int i = 0;
    printf("Enter 3 numbers");

    for( i = 0; i< 3; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &temp->d);
        temp->next = newNode;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    temp->next = NULL;
    printf("%d \n", temp->d);

    return 0;
}
```

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think there is more than one node in that list? *You only allocated ONE node*. I think you need to review whatever linked list example you're learning from, because all `temp` is doing in that loop is continually pointing to the same node over and over again.

Comment: Also, you only ever call `printf()` on the last node.

Comment: You need to call `malloc()` every time you want to create a node. In your case you need to make 3 `malloc()` calls. Also, no more malloc call is needed in `printList()`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't even bother with `printList` review because it's never called (as Tim pointed out).

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with the following code :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <alloca.h>

typedef int DATA;

struct Node
{
    DATA d;
    struct Node *next;
};

void printList(struct Node **head)
{
    struct Node *newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *temp;
    temp = *head;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
       printf("%d \n", temp->d);
       temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Node *newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *head = newNode;
    struct Node *temp = newNode;
    head->d = 1;
    int i = 0;
    printf("Enter 3 numbers");

    for( i = 0; i< 3; i++)
    {
        struct Node *newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        scanf("%d", &temp->d);
        temp->next = newNode;
        temp = temp->next;

    }

    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Here you need to declare the `newNode` in the loop also while taking the input. As, the current value is over-writted, the old value is lossed and only the value of last node is printed.

Also while printing, check for `temp->next!=Null` instead of `temp!=NULL`

Comment: I added the close brace that was missing in the question too (I fixed the question too).  Where do you call the printing function?  Have you tested your code?  Presumably not since the original code would not have compiled.

Comment: As per your code, one additional node would get created on the last iteration which will not have any data and will print garbage.

Comment: To everyone who contributed to this question: Thank you, sorry for any foolish mistakes I may have made, I am still pretty new at this

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- You are not creating the list properly. You are allocating memory for only one node and playing around with pointers improperly causing the linked list to be pointed to the same memory
- You are not calling printList function at all
- It is not clear why you are allocating memory again in printList whereas it should be printing the already created list
- Also, no need to pass double pointer for printList as you are not modifying the list.

Though you should be understanding and doing the changes yourself, I am providing a below modified program which I hope will help you understand the mistakes in your code.

Please see the below modified version of the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <alloca.h>

typedef int DATA;
struct Node
{
    DATA d;
    struct Node *next;
};


void printList(struct Node *head)
{
    struct Node *temp = head;

    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d \n", temp->d);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

struct Node *createNode()
{
    struct Node *newNode;

    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (NULL == newNode)
        return NULL;

    memset(newNode, 0, sizeof(struct Node));
    return newNode;
}

int main()
{
    struct Node *newNode = NULL;
    struct Node *headNode = NULL;
    struct Node *temp = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    int data = 0;

    printf("Enter 3 numbers\n");

    for( i = 0; i< 3; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &data);
        newNode = createNode();
        if (NULL == newNode)
            break;

        newNode->d = data;

        if (headNode == NULL)
        {
            headNode = newNode;
            temp = newNode;
        } 
        else
        {
            temp->next = newNode;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    printList(headNode);    
    return 0;
}
```